# Multiple parameters for a single method

Tags: java, void

I don't know how simple this would be or if it is possible but I can't seem to find any information on it. For a method is there a way to set multiple parameters.

For example in this public void it is required you call a component and and string when you call the method in your java file.

```
public void testMethod(Component c, String s)
{
    //Do Something
}
```

Is there way to say `public void testMethod(Component c, String d)` or `public void testMethod(Component c, int i)` and when the method is called either could be specified?

Comment: Yes, it's called "method overloading".

Comment: You could test it yourself very easily. Yes, it's possible.

Comment: Please get your basics straight. Read up some tutorials like [this](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/methods.html)

Comment: You spent 15 minutes wondering whether something like this is possible. You spent 10 minutes typing this question. We spent 30 seconds reading your question and providing you an answer in the comments. I assure you that the Java compiler can compile a small program like this in less than 25 minutes and 30 seconds . If you don't have a Java compiler, a quick google search for *same method with different parameters* would have still been faster than posting a question.

Answer (score 3):

It's called method overloading. Just create them as separate methods and the compiler will (usually) infer the right one based on your input values.

Answer (score 2):

Yes this is possible and is an inportant concept.  This particular technique is called function overloading.  Suppose you declare 2 functions like:

```
  public void testMethod(Component c, String d) {} //function 1
```

and

```
  public void testMethod(Component c, int d) {} //function 2
```

You can then call these functions from main as:

```
  testMethod(c,"Hello")   //calls function 1
  testMethod(c,1)   //calls function 2
```

Comment: Copy paste failure. I think both calls would call fnct 1

Comment: You still have a case problem with your method examples.

Answer (score 1):

It is called "method overloading". Any two methods can have the same name, as long as the parameters are different. For example:

```
public void doStuff(String string, int integer) {}
public void doStuff(Object object, float flt) {}
```

This also applies for constructors:

```
public Thing(String name, int id) {}
public Thing(Object object, long id) {}
```

However, take the following two methods for example:

```
public void doStuff(String string) {}
public void doStuff(Object object) {}
```

Now, call the method `doStuff(null)`. The compiler cannot infer which one to use; in which case, you will get a compilation error. This also occurs in constructors (just to get it out of the way, constructors are almost the same as methods).

Answer (score 0):

Simply stated, you can.

```
public void testFunction(Component c, String s) {
    // Handle on a string
}

public void testFunction(Component c, int i) {
    // Handle on integer
}
```

This is called method overloading.  Whichever type is passed will cause your function call to use the appropriate method.  The order of the parameters is still important.

Comment: +1 for stating that the order of parameters is important. Many people forget that. Myself too, sometimes